# Is there a papaya substitute in salads?

Tags: substitutions, fruit, papaya

Is there a substitute for green papayas in green papaya salad?

The papayas in U.S. supermarket are not the same, even if you use them green.

Answer (score 3):

The "key property" of the papaya and the reason why it is used is its texture: crunchyness. I think you can use anything else that is crunchy and has a quite neutral taste, like cucumber peel, cabbage, kohlrabi, carrots, young lotus stalks (like [the ones](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/another-oddity-of-lotus-roots/) in [this receipe](http://wanderingchopsticks.blogspot.de/2010/03/goi-cu-sen-non-tom-thit-vietnamese.html), not [these](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Lotus_root.jpg/308px-Lotus_root.jpg)), or unripe mango. I had them in salads similar to the green papaya salad and found that these ingedients are quite neutral in taste.

After all, replacing the papaya makes the salad to not be a green papaya salad anymore. ;) You could try other *[gỏi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%E1%BB%99m)* -- [vietnamese salad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_cuisine#Salads) -- receipes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are a few options for you.

[This recipe](http://www.templeofthai.com/recipes/papaya_salad.php) recommends:

> But, if you don't [have] a green papaya, try substituting **shredded cucumber**, **carrot** and **daikon radish**.

[Another recipe](http://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/spicy-green-papaya-salad) notes the possibility of using:

> You will probably have to go to Chinatown to find green (unripe) papaya. Alternatively, substitute a crisp vegetable such as **jicama** or **celery**.